# Showing IP address on Textbox after select combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox, ipv4

I want to show IP address on a textbox after i select network adapter from the combobox list. This is the working code for showing adapter list on combobox.

```
    Dim ni = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
    Dim niEthernet = ni.Where(Function(x) x.NetworkInterfaceType =
                      Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
    ComboBox1.DataSource = niEthernet.Select(Function(x) x.Name).ToList()
```

I have no problem in selecting the adapter. My problem is i want the textbox to show IPv4 address depends on what adapter i choose from combobox list. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the SelectedIndexChanged event, do something based on the Combobox selected item:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    'will set the textbox to the selected item in the combobox
    Textbox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem

    'or set it based on the combo selection
    Select case Combo1.SelectedItem
       Case "Local Connection"
         Textbox1.Text = "some IP address"
       Case "Something else"
         Textbox1.Text = "something else"
    End Select

End Sub
```